# pinterest access tokenの取得やり方が分からない。

Tags: python, python3, oauth, flask, webapi

pinterestのapiを使ってアプリを作成したいのですが、access tokenの取得方法が分かりません。
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/
ドキュメントを読んだのですが、Postmanを使ったやり方しか理解できません。毎度アプリで取得して使いたいのでpythonのプログラムから取得したいのです。
hatenaのアクセストークンを取得するときに以下のコードを作成したのですが、これにどのようにpinterestの情報を入れたら良いのでか分かりません。
`appID`と`appSecret`の2つしかpinterestではないです。oauthのバージョンが違うなどでしょうか？
一日中、探しても出てこなかったのでここで質問させていただきます。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, redirect, session
from furl import furl
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key ='????????????????'
#urlをこんな感じにする。https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=たぶん自分のappID&response_type=token
OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' #pinでいうclient IDに当たる
OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

TEMPORARY_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST_URL = '????????????'
RESOURCE_OWNER_AUTHORIZATION_URL = '????????????'
TOKEN_REQUEST_URL = '??????????????????'

CALLBACK_URI = 'http://0.0.0.0:9000/callback_page'
SCOPE = {'scope': 'read_public,write_public'}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    oauth = OAuth1Session(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, callback_uri=CALLBACK_URI)
    #以下のコードがよくわからん
    fetch_respone = oauth.fetch_request_token(TEMPORARY_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST_URL, data=SCOPE)

    session['request_token'] = fetch_respone.get('oauth_token')
    session['request_token_secret'] = fetch_respone.get('oauth_token_secret')

    redirect_url = furl(RESOURCE_OWNER_AUTHORIZATION_URL)
    redirect_url.args['oauth_token'] = session['request_token']
    return redirect(redirect_url.url)

@app.route('/callback_page')
def callback_page():
    #verifierってなんですの？
    verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')
    oauth = OAuth1Session(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, resource_owner_key=session['request_token'], resource_owner_secret=session['request_token_secret'], verifier=verifier)

    access_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(TOKEN_REQUEST_URL)
    access_token = access_tokens.get('oauth_token')
    access_secret = access_tokens.get('oauth_token_secret')
    return "アクセストークン: {}, アクセストークン・シークレットキー: {}".format(access_token, access_secret)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=9000)
```

Postmanを使用する場合は以下の情報を入力するみたいです。
[image: postman情報]